# What happened to Budd?

Tags: kill-bill

In [Kill Bill Vol 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0378194/?ref_=nv_sr_2), We get to see more of Budd and his story. But it's not the story of a world class assassin, but one of a broken, submissive man who looks like he has nothing to live for.

We see proof of this in the place he lives. A run down trailer home in the middle of the desert. He works at a strip club where his boss treats him like crap. He calls Elle to sell the Hanzo sword.

What happened to Budd that caused him go from a world class assassin with a good lifestyle to what was depicted in his chapter? All the other assassins in the Deadly Viper Assassin Squad were doing fine (until they get killed of course).

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/30p40m/kill_bill_what_caused_bill_and_buds_falling_out/ I am willing to accept this as canon for Budd and Bill's falling out.

Comment: The El Paso reference I never picked up on but I'd believe that answers my question 100%

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, first of all the following is entirely speculation by me, since we don't get too much insight into his backstory in the movie. It might only be a first start, as I might have to rewatch it to further substantiate any of this with some specific dialogue or other hints.

That being said, it seems to me as if *Budd* pretty much *wanted* to distance himself from *Bill*'s whole business and that previous life as a world class assassin (if he ever was one). **He seems a bit disillusioned to me.** For example when he says to *Elle* something like (forgive me for not recounting it word-accurate):

> This woman deserves her revenge and we deserve to die for what we did to her.

In the same way, if I remember correctly, he said something like that he sold his *Hanzo* sword, an item of absolutely unestimable value to any of the others in *Bill*'s crew. So he obviously wasn't engaged in the matter with his heart and soul anymore (if he ever was).

It is unclear, though, if it actually was their assassination of *The Bride* that caused this change of mind in *Budd* or if he never really was so much of a real member of the gang. To me it rather seemed that **he never was so much devoted to the whole business let alone such an established member as the others**, but was primarily part of the gang because he is *Bill*'s brother (neither is he a woman nor a Kung Fu magician either, if I remember correctly).

Comment: Some good points. Budd probably was the black sheep of the group considering Elle's treatment of him and yeah, he wasn't a master swordsman or skilled at kung-fu (at least we never saw him doing any of that). 

But even still, moving on from the gang doesn't mean he had to succumb to self-pitty and let himself be treated like crap by others. Then again, maybe that was his character the whole time, we just didn't see it as such.

Comment: Thing is he **had** a Hanzo sword (which implies he was a world class swordsman since Hanzo didn't just make them to be souvenirs) and he **didn't** sell it (though he said he did.) Maybe he got disillusioned but these things don't support the idea that he was never core the gang or not a master assassin.

Comment: @matt_black I'm not sure the sword implies him being able to wield it like a master. Sure, *Hanzo* didn't make them for every passing tourist, but for such a man as *Bill* to give it to his brother, maybe. I didn't remember that the movie clarified that he did not sell it, but I might as well have forgotten that. But he nevertheless said he'd sold it at least. I agree that the answer isn't too substantial, though.

Comment: Probably a metaphor of Madsen's involvement in Tarantino's films: they're good buddies so he comes over, sticks around.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Budd's Hattori Hanzo sword was from Bill, so there's no indication it came from Hanzo himself.

Second, we never learn why he & Bill are estranged.

This is pure speculation, but I think Budd had a gambling problem, so when the group disbanded (which I think happened after they killed the bride & co because it sent Bill into a depression), without a leader they all kind of went their own way, with Bill as sporadic leader/snake charmer/wrangler on assassin jobs... Budd seems like much more of a fuck-up than Bill, so without Bill's leadership, he probably spiraled himself, but with gambling, drugs, women & booze... With no money, and unwilling to sell his Hanzo sword (the gift from Bill, not black mamba's sword), probably for sentimental reasons.

Tarantino is great at character development, so I bet he has answers for all this stuff. I wish he'd make a Kill Bill version of [Animatrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Animatrix) or [Clone Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_%282008_TV_series%29) (animated or live action), to fill in some of the questions.

Side-note: the reason I think he kept his sentimental sword: because most drunks/gamblers are emotionally stunted & sensitive.

Comment: If my links are wrong, feel free to fix them.